# Find deep children in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I've searched the docs and web throughly but cannot find any solution for this seemingly trivial problem. Let's say we have a collection called "states". The states collection has a document that looks like this:

```
{
    'name': 'New York',
    'towns': [
        {
            'name': 'Town A',
            'buildings':[
                {
                    'name': 'Town Hall',
                    'open_days': [False, True, True, True, True, True, False],
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Fire Department',
                    'open_days': [True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Car Dealership',
                    'open_days': [False, True, True, True, True, True, True],
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Town B',
            'buildings':[
                {
                    'name': 'Town Hall',
                    'open_days': [False, True, True, True, True, True, False],
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Police Department',
                    'open_days': [True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Karate Dojo',
                    'open_days': [False, True, False, True, False, True, False],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this data, `open_days` represents whether a building is open or closed on a particular day of the week (index 0 being Sunday for example).

I just want to query the data to pull up all the buildings that are open on Sunday (index 0).

I've tried several odd syntaxes to no avail, is there an easy solution to this? If it matters, I am querying using PyMongo.

Comment: You'll need to switch to using a different style of storing the data -- you can't use values as keys and do a generic search. So, `"Town Hall"` for example can't be a key.

Comment: Okay that's good to know, thank you. I'm fairly new to MongoDB. I've edited the post to restructure the data.

Comment: A query that does what you want would be: `db.test.find({"towns.buildings.open_days.0": true})`, however, it will fetch the entire document. You may want to consider breaking the data into distinct documents so the query results can be more targeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually depends. First of all there are a few ways to restructure your data a little bit to make it more easy to query and to extract. You don't have to restructure it at all, but if you can I think it would be beneficial.

Some refactoring suggestions:

- First of all you might want to split this single large document into multiple documents. Just take out documents from array `towns` and make each one a standalone document in your collection. Add state `name` to each. Embedding docs in Mongo is a good idea, but it seems to me that this is a bit over too much. I would even go further extracting each building into a top level document. The reasons for this are: you might not be able to fit all buildings in a large city into a single document (size limit 16Mb). Even if you are able to fit all buildings into a single document your queries will be quite inefficient if you want to select only small part of that document.
- Change your array to hold integers corresponding to indexes of weekdays, i.e. Sunday == 0, etc. This will make it simpler and more efficient to query.

So your data would look this way:

```
{
  "stateName": "New York",
  "townName": "Town A",
  "buildingName": "Town Hall",
  "open_days": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Now you can find a building in a city that's open on Monday (1):

```
db.buildings.find({"stateName": "New York", "townName": "Town A", "open_days": 1});
```

If you don't want to restructure your data take a look at `$elemMatch` [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) which projects matched element of an array. You can also take a look at `$` [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/). However, both these operators do not solve your problem because they return first matched element in the array.

You can also use aggregation framework, but you'll be limited to number of results that fit in a single doc (16Mb), won't be able to have a cursor to results, it will be slower and it's over complicated for what you want to do.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I actually wasn't aware of the 16Mb size limit on documents. I thought the entire benefit of MongoDB (other than schemaless) was that you could reduce joins by nesting objects. In a situation where each state, town, building needed to have its own data and reference each other, it almost seems like MySQL would work better. Would you agree?

Comment: I think in no-sql world you design your schema around queries, not the other way around like normalized SQL tables. So in this schema it would depend on how much data you would have and what kind of queries you run on it. It could make sense to have buildings nested in a single Street document, or a district. I think in your example it's just too much data to embed. Contrast it for example with a blog post that has embedded comments. If you have limited size comments and fairly small (100s) number of comments it would usually make sense to embed data.

Comment: You always have to find the right balance between performing multiple queries and fetching too much data in a single one.

Comment: Perhaps the main point in choosing between sql/no-sql database would be how well it will scale, and whether you really need transaction support. If you want great horizontal scalability and don't do too much heavy transactional stuff then Mongo is perhaps a better choice.

Comment: Well, just to make it clear there are no real joins in this example. You don't even have to query other collections to find state name or town name for example. You could store ids instead of names too. The point is that you usually have that state id or name and just fetch all other data. No need to join it even in sql world ;). However if you want to join on application level, for instance to insert state name into each doc/row it's easier to do with JSON rather than with SQL result set or DB entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

What you could use here is aggregation framework. You will find lots of nice examples on aggregation framework in [MongoDB docs - Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)
What you could be interested in in particular would be `$unwind` pipeline operator which *peels off the elements of an array individually, and returns a stream of documents. $unwind returns one document for every member of the unwound array within every source document.*

Here is an example, I hope it provides what you expect it to do:

```
> db.collection.aggregate(
... { $match : { "towns.buildings.open_days.0" : true }},
... { $unwind : "$towns"},
... { $unwind : "$towns.buildings"},
... { $match : { "towns.buildings.open_days.0" : true }}
... )
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52e5ba3beb849fd797d10839"),
            "name" : "New York",
            "towns" : {
                "name" : "Town A",
                "buildings" : {
                    "name" : "Fire Department",
                    "open_days" : [
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52e5ba3beb849fd797d10839"),
            "name" : "New York",
            "towns" : {
                "name" : "Town B",
                "buildings" : {
                    "name" : "Police Department",
                    "open_days" : [
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```